# TRIGGERS insert same table - PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Here's my problem:

I have to transform something like this

[image: INICIAL FORM]

Into this in the same table

[image: FINAL FORM]

I've tried triggers but I have mutating issues, I have no control about the inserts but I need to do that for every row with value larger than 1.
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of transactions you're looking at, it may not be a feasible approach, but you might try something along these lines:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER {TRIGGER NAME}
BEFORE INSERT ON {TABLE HERE}
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_val INTEGER;
BEGIN
   l_val := :new.value - 1;

   IF l_val > 0 THEN
      :new.value := 1;

      FOR i IN 1..l_val LOOP
         INSERT INTO {TABLE HERE}
         VALUES (:new.name, 1);
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
END {TRIGGER NAME};
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use view and instead of trigger.

1. Creating table `create table testing_trig (c char(1), i integer);`
2. Creating view `create or replace view testing_trig_view as select * from testing_trig;`
3. Creating trigger

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER testing_trg
> INSTEAD OF INSERT
> ON testing_trig_view
> BEGIN
>   FOR i IN 1 .. :NEW.i
>   LOOP
>     INSERT INTO testing_trig VALUES (:NEW.c, 1);
>   END LOOP;
> END;
> /
> ```

4. Insert into view `insert into testing_trig_view values ('A', 3);`
5. Validate

> ```
> SQL> select * from testing_trig;
>
> C    I
> - ----------
> A    1
> A    1
> A    1
> ```